# Soma de tabelas de acordo com o id da sessão

Tags: php, mysql

O que estou fazendo é a soma da quantidade de tabelas de acordo com o id do usuário que estiver logado, do modo que estou fazendo nenhum valor é demostrado.

Banco:

```
id      id_affiliate      user_ip          date
 1                2       162.70.25.00     2015-11-06 08:49:47
 2                1       162.70.25.00     2015-11-06 09:49:47
 3                2       162.70.25.00     2015-11-06 10:49:47     
 4                2       162.70.25.00     2015-11-06 11:49:47
 2                1       162.70.25.00     2015-11-06 00:49:47
```

Código:

```
 <?

    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');

          if (!$connect) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("database", $connect);

    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id_affiliate FROM easy_affiliate_stats WHERE id_affiliate = . "$_SESSION["id_affiliate"], $connect);
    //Conta quantos registros possuem na tabela
    $total= mysql_num_rows($consulta);
    //Mostra o valor
    echo "Atualmente há $total registros";
    ?>
```

Comment: O id_affiliate está retornando certo? dentro do SESSION

Comment: A página está vindo em branco, não apresenta nenhum erro dentro do localhost.

Comment: Postei uma resposta pra você.

Comment: Ao enviar a requisição, a página retorna em branco, nenhum erro e nenhuma informação na página. :/

Comment: O erro está na concatenação da consulta

Comment: Ok. Estou utilizando o código que você me enviou, a página está abrindo normalmente, mais me retorna o valor de 0 registros.

Comment: Se está retornando zero, você não está passando corretamente o $_SESSION, dê um echo $_SESSION["id_affiliate"] pra ver o que retorna.

Comment: Fiz o informado e não retornou nenhum valor.

Comment: Então o problema está na sua session que não está funcionando. Está iniciando a session no começo do arquivo? session_start();

Comment: Não estava, adicionei e ainda continua retornando 0, será por quê os cadastros ficam salvos em outra tabela?

Comment: Conseguiu fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or print mysql_error();
    mysql_select_db("database");

    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id_affiliate FROM easy_affiliate_stats WHERE id_affiliate = '$_SESSION[id_affiliate]'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($consulta) >= 0){
        echo "Atualmente há ".mysql_num_rows($consulta)." registros";
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum registro foi encontrado";  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting('0');
   mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die ('erro-01');
   mysql_select_db("database") or die ('erro-02');

$total= mysql_num_rows( mysql_query("SELECT id_affiliate FROM easy_affiliate_stats WHERE id_affiliate ='$_SESSION[id_affiliate]'"));


  if($total >= 0){
        echo "Atualmente há ".$total." registros";
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum registro foi encontrado";  
    }


?>
```

Comment: simples... dessa forma é pra funcionar espero ter ajudado